# Corda Nodes Monitoring

Tags: corda

I have Corda network (3 nodes + 1 Notary Node) running locally on my windows system.

I am reading through this document @ https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html

Node Statistics are exposed through JMX beans to Jolokia agent running at the start of each node. I see jolokia agents tarting for each of the node at different ports. Ex - Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/jolokia/

I am using Hawtio dashboard to see Corda node JVM statistics exposed through Jolokia agents storage. While hawtio is smart enough to discover jolokia agents started at different port for each Corda Node, i am not able to see required statistics displayed on the dashboard.

I have tried setting up jmxMonitoringHttpPort in each of the node.conf with jokia port for each node. But Node is not starting because Jolokia agent is not running at target port message.

I have downloaded binaries of Jolokia agent and ran it on a unused port in system, configured node.conf for each file pointing to this port. But i am still not seeing statistics for any of the node.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try with the obligation CorDapp project https://github.com/corda/obligation-cordapp#instructions-for-setting-up with ".runnodes" script, because the nodes are running with jolokia agent enabled.

alternatively you can run a single node with `java -Dcapsule.jvm.args="-javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=7033" -jar corda.jar` and see if this works.